# how to use property value in Directory Listing Data Source on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsr223, directory-listing

I am setting a property value through JSR223 pre-procesor and want to use this property for source directory in Directory Listing Data Source but, not been succesful. Here's how i am trying to do it.Have i missed something?

[setpropertyvalue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCTxl.png)

[usepropertyindirectorylisting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5V79.png)

The reason I want to do this is because I want to use files from different folder in each thread. I have named folders as ABC1, ABC2, ABC3 etc...and that is why i want to use thread number function for ABC${threadNum}. But, i am not able to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine given you set the property **before** the directory listing config is initialized.

Take a look at [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

```
0. Configuration elements
1. Pre-Processors
2. Timers
3. Sampler
4. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)
```

So as you can see [Configuration Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) are being executed before anything else so you either need to

- define your property in another configuration element which will be executed before the Directory Listing Config such as [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)
- or move your code to [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/)
- or provide the property value via [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: I am using directory listing as the files are picked one by one in a random order from the directory. is there any other way i can achieve this? The folders are named like ABC(one),ABC(two),ABC3 etc...and each thread should pick files from different folder. And, i am using threadNum function to concatenate at the end of the filePath. i am doing this in pre-processor as: def threadNum = ctx.getThreadNum(); def fileDir = vars.get("ReadyToUpload"); def uploadFile = fileDir+threadNum; Any suggestions?